# Conditional coloring in DC chart

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter, reductio

I wanted to comment on the following: 
[Conditional coloring in dc charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178916/conditional-coloring-in-dc-charts)

How can we define the lower and upper bounds of a colorDomain to reflect automatically the min and max values of a specific group ? For instance applying a filter, I want to make sure that I use the gradient of colors green to red even if the min and max values after filter have changed.

Should I use reductio to capture the reactive min and max values ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not done automatically because often the colors will have absolute meanings and should not be rescaled. It's very much like `elasticX` and `elasticY`.

It's pretty easy to calculate it automatically - just set an event handler to call `calculateColorDomain` each time the chart is redrawn:

```
chart.on('preRedraw', function() {
    chart.calculateColorDomain();
});
```

[It should really be an option.](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1150)